# Cadence transistor size

Tags: transistors, cadence

In Cadence software, I am trying to modify (W/L) for the CMOS transistors, I am using GDPK 180 library. Can I modify the length of the transistors to be different? or it should be the same for all transistors?

Comment: It is so possible, you can watch some video in youtube. just search "Cadence Virtuoso" in that

Comment: It is not software, but PDK dependent, and I see no reason why you couldn't do that.